# How to use EPS files in a WPF or Silverlight application?

Tags: wpf, silverlight, xaml, vector-graphics, eps

I have a few images in EPS format which I would like to use in my WPF application. Is this possible?

If not, is there a way to convert them to XAML so I can use them directly in WPF? I don't have a budget for Expression Design or Adobe Illustrator, and there are only a few images to convert.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use Inkscape http://www.inkscape.org/. It will allow you to import EPS file, but you'll need to have GhostScript installed for that. Inkscape uses SVG format and will allow you to export from SVG to XAML.