# Converting EPS to Xaml

Tags: wpf, xaml, vector, eps

I have bunch of EPS vector files that I want to convert to Xaml (WPF version, not Silverlight). What's the best tool for the job (Preferably a free one)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use Blend (3+ only), to import EPS.  Not sure about free tools, but if it's a one off you could just grab the trial of Blend 3.

Correction:

You can't import EPS with Blend, only .ai.  You can convert your EPS to .ai and then import into Blend.

Alternatively, there's similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1069160/how-to-use-eps-files-in-a-wpf-or-silverlight-application) that might help.

Comment: Actually I have Blend 3.0, but I don't see where I can import a EPS file into a WPF project. Could you elaborate?

Comment: Blend 4.0 also works, but Blend 2012 does not support Adobe Import. It's in the menu, but is permanently disabled.